# How do I remove trash icon from GNOME desktop?

Tags: gnome, icons, gnome-shell, trash, desktop-icons

How do I remove the "Trash" icon from GNOME 3 desktop? I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME shell.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### Up to Ubuntu 18.10

You may use *(GNOME) Tweaks* (aka GNOME Tweak Tool) to do that. First install it (if it is not installed) by running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

or

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Launch *Tweaks* and go to *Desktop* section. Then toggle off (or uncheck) the **Trash** (or Rubbish bin or Wastebasket) option under "*Icons on Desktop*".

[image]

Alternatively you may run the following command in Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible false
```

Comment: Just tested it in a VM. Works as advertised. Tested the GUI solution with tweak tools and the command line solution.

Comment: Can also confirm the terminal command works as advertised

Comment: For the CLI-oriented, the command is `gnome-tweaks`.

Comment: @tomislav They're the [same thing](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029575/480481).

Comment: @pomsky Yes, just thought if anyone wants to start it from the CLI, that's the name.

Comment: on 19.10 tab Desktop no longer appears ... instead in tweaks hit Extensions -> wrench on Desktop icons and switch off trash

Comment: @scott Yes, because the way desktop icons are handled is changed fundamentally (handler changed from Nautilus to a shell extension), and this is the case since Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 13):

<sub>After following [Exien's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212360/) on Ubuntu 20.04, the GUI became extremely slow and unresponsive. I had to reinstall Ubuntu even after reverting the value to true which did not fix the problem it generates.</sub>

#### In Ubuntu 20.04

It is actually easy:

1. Search for Extensions (preinstalled) in the Activities overview.

   [image: Search for Extensions (comes installed ready)]
2. Click on the Settings gear icon next to the Desktop Icons toggle

   [image: Click on the settings gear icon next to the Desktop Icons toggle]
3. Toggle icons as required

   [image: Toggle icons as required]

Comment: It's probably just a red herring; your issues may have appeared coincidentally after running the command, but most likely *only* the command itself is not the *cause*. Running the command does (under the hood) exactly what toggling off in the Extensions app does.

Answer (score 6):

#### Ubuntu 19.04 and later

The following terminal command works:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash false
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It's annoying that the developers didn't just provide this option in the properties menu of the icon or in a more accessible place in settings

Comment: Does not work in ubuntu 22.04 for me, I get `No such schema “org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons”`

Answer (score 1):

The extensions don't work for ubuntu 21.04
just right click on the desktop and select "settings" you will find your options there

Answer (score 0):

If the Extensions app doesn't show up in the Activities menu (as it did for me) you can use:

```
gnome-extensions prefs desktop-icons@csoriano
```

to open the window shown [in Brendan's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1247717/618353).

You can also hide all icons (including files) with:

```
gnome-extensions disable desktop-icons@csoriano
```