# place icon in side bar rather than desktop in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-dock

Today I have upgraded to 17.10 from 17.04 . After update there are several icons like trash , mounted drive are showing in desktop which were shown in sidebar in earlier version . How can I place those in sidebar like in earlier version of ubuntu .

[image]

Comment: Removing the icons from desktop is [easy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965881/how-to-remove-trash-icon-from-desktop-on-ubuntu-17-10), but placing them in the dock is not.

Comment: See this for a hacky workaround for the Trash icon: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067164/remove-trash-icon-from-desktop-and-add-to-ubuntu-dock-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

To hide desktop icons install GNOME Tweak Tool (New name Tweaks) in your ubuntu. For installation instructions check this **[link](https://connectwww.com/how-to-install-gnome-tweak-tool-or-tweaks-on-ubuntu/60665/)**.

[image: GNOME tweak tool hide desktop icons]