# Is the GNOME Tweaks package in Software the same as installing gnome-tweak-tool?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-tweaks

Following a fresh hardware install I found "GNOME Tweaks" in the Software app and installed it. Subsequently I ran in terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

To my surprise it installed another package, not an upgrade.

The Tweak Tool works fine, but I'm wondering if I now have 2 versions of the tool installed, and if so which one should I remove?

**Update**
I found out that `gnome-tweaks` is the prime package to have installed:

```
$ apt show gnome-tweaks
...
Breaks: gnome-tweak-tool (<= 3.27.4)
Replaces: gnome-tweak-tool (<= 3.27.4)
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
...

$ apt show gnome-tweak-tool
...
Source: gnome-tweaks
Depends: gnome-tweaks
...
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, the `gnome-tweaks-tool` and `gnome-tweaks` packages correspond to the same application.

The package was renamed to `gnome-tweaks` with [GNOME 3.26](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.26/) (Ubuntu 17.10), but it continues to provide `gnome-tweak-tool` as a transitional package, which can safely be removed (is used for those who upgrade), as you can see here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-tweaks/3.28.1-1

Comment: Just one pointer, the change of name actually happened before 18.04. This was introduced with GNOME version 3.26 (hence Ubuntu 17.10) (see the [release notes](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.26/)).

Answer (score 8):

*GNOME Tweaks* is the new name for *GNOME Tweak Tool* as stated in the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029583/307523). The [release notes of GNOME 3.26 (Ubuntu 17.10)](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.26/) states:

> - Tweak Tool has been renamed to Tweaks and has gained three new settings: a switch to move window buttons to the left or right, a Disable While Typing option for touchpads and an option to show the battery percentage in the top bar. There has also been a good amount of clean up and refinement.

For a full list of tweak tools in 18.04 (I'm using Unity Tweak Tool) run this command:

```
$ apt list | grep tweak
gajim-rostertweaks/bionic,bionic 1.0.0-3 all
gnome-tweak-tool/bionic,bionic 3.28.1-1 all
gnome-tweaks/bionic,bionic 3.28.1-1 all
mate-tweak/bionic,bionic 18.04.16-1 all
mousetweaks/bionic,bionic,now 3.12.0-4 amd64 [installed]
tweak/bionic 3.02-2 amd64
unity-tweak-tool/bionic,bionic,now 0.0.7ubuntu4 all [installed]
```