# Brightness Control not working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, lenovo, intel, backlight

I have both Windows 10 & Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS installed on my [Lenovo Legion Y740-15IRHg](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-Legion-Y740-15IRHg-81UH001XGE.438495.0.html), with a dual boot setup. I also have Nvidia 440 driver installed.

Currently I'm having issue with controlling my brightness on Ubuntu. Here are a few approaches I tried and none of them worked out.

1. Modifying `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` directly
2. Updating `acpi_backlight` argument in Grub's config `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `vendor`, `video` & `native`
3. Using `xbacklight`

Anyone has any idea how to get this resolved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the are some tweaks you could try   https://extensions.gnome.org/

Comment: gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepUp

gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepDown

Comment: @pierrely I don't really know what's the [extensions.gnome.org], but running the command directly gives me this

Comment: ```Warning: Introspection data indicates 0 parameters but more was passed
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Type of message, '(ss)', does not match expected type '()'
(According to introspection data, you need to pass no arguments)```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029575/is-the-gnome-tweaks-package-in-software-the-same-as-installing-gnome-tweak-tools