# Remove persistent Home and Trash desktop icons on 20.04 / gnome-flashback

Tags: gnome, 20.04, desktop-icons, gnome-flashback

I have a fresh installation of Focal Fossa, 20.04 LTS. I have installed gnome-flashback with `apt-get install gnome-session-flashback -qq`. Once I log in I see two annoying icons on the desktop: home and trash. There is no way I can get rid of them...
Could someone please provide a **tested** solution?

I have been trying various options I found on the internet but no luck so far: the `gsettings` already reports `false` for the icons, Gnome Extensions seems broken and cannot display anything, Gnome Tweak Tools do not show any option related to icons on the left bar...

Comment: Couple of quick questions, *which* `gsettings` command reports `false`? What does Tweak Tools not showing any option related to *icons on the left bar* has to do with it?

Comment: A solution by muktupavels below works fine; indeed - my error was to use gnome-shell instead of gnome-flashback.

Comment: This is why providing a comprehensive technical details is important. From "`gsettings` already reports `false`" I assumed you ran the correct commands (as in the answer by muktupavels) and still it failed for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be removed with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-flashback.desktop.icons show-home false
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-flashback.desktop.icons show-trash false
```

Extensions are GNOME *(`gnome-shell`)* only things, won't work in GNOME Flashback *(`gnome-flashback`)*.

Comment: Thank you!  Finally!

Answer (score 1):

the answer by muktupavels did not work:

gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-flashback.desktop.icons show-home false

No such schema “org.gnome.gnome-flashback.desktop.icons”

(weird, why .gnome-flashback. when you say "won't work in GNOME Flashback"? )

I did the following. Find the right schema:

gsettings list-schemas | grep icons

org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons

So tried this, which did work:

gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false

gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons  show-trash false

Comment: This is because the question and the answer by muktupavels is about GNOME **Flashback** (which needs to be installed manually over standard Ubuntu). From the commands that worked for you, it is evident that you're using a *standard* GNOME session on Ubuntu; you don't have GNOME Flashback at all.

Comment: Oops. I entered the comment since I was looking for an answer to the same problem and  muktupavels' answer did it for me with a little modification, so I documented it.

Comment: You were probably looking for this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/965881/480481